# Is there a way to have ConfigParser 'not' return a list

Tags: python, configparser

I'm trying to have ConfigParser read from a file with multiple sections. Then I would have my code iterate through each section with a for loop and assign the current available keys to a variable.

From there, I call re.search to search for those current available keys within a separate file.

Here's somewhat of an idea (bear with me as I'm not the best with this language)

```
import re
import sys
import ConfigParser

inputfile = raw_input("Enter config file: ")
scanfile = raw_input("Enter name of file to scan through: ")
searchfile = open(scanfile,'r')
config = config.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read(inputfile)
for ch in config.sections():
  keys = config.options(ch)
  person = ch
  for line in scanfile:
   if re.search(keys,line):
     outfile = open(person,'w')  
     print >> outfile,line
```

However, configparser returns a list which is breaking re.search. Is there a way to have it return a tuple, or better yet, just the bare options without []?

Is there another module that can also search (find() doesn't work for what I'm trying to do).

Thank you

Comment: you can cast the return of the method with tuple() to transform a list to a tuple.

Comment: `l = [1,2,3] tuple(l) -> (1,2,3)`

Comment: why are you searching the string scanfile?

Comment: So ... The problem is that `keys` is a list and you want it to be a regular expression or something?  couldn't you just join the keys into a regular expression that looks for any of them?  `regex = '|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in keys)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the tip; I ended up getting a error of "TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern". I'm going to tinker with it a bit or try converting to a string and stripping []. Also, scanfile contains a separate text file that I want to search through for the keys that ConfigParser reads from a config file.

Comment: @mgilson Yes, that is the problem. I will give your solution a whirl shortly. Note that the keys are dynamic and will change regularly, hence me not wanting to hardcode them in anyway (I'm aware this would have been way easier)

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve here? this just sounds like an overly complex attempt to do something simple...

please supply a concrete version of what output and input is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the any key in the  keys list are in the line:

```
import re
import sys
import ConfigParser
inputfile = raw_input("Enter config file: ")
scanfile = raw_input("Enter name of file to scan through: ")
searchfile = open(scanfile,'r')
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read(inputfile)
for ch in config.sections():
  keys = set(config.options(ch))
  person = ch
  for line in searchfile: # iterate over file object not the string
      if any(k in keys for k in line.split()):
         outfile = open(person,'w')
         print >> outfile,line
searchfile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Using `with` and a few change to how you name your variables:

```
input_file = raw_input("Enter config file: ")
scan_file = raw_input("Enter name of file to scan through: ")
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read(input_file)
with open(scan_file, 'r') as search_file:: # with closes your files automatically
    for person in config.sections():
        keys = set(config.options(person))
        for line in search_file:
            if any(k in keys for k in line.split()): # check if any key is in the line
                with open(person, 'w') as out_file:
                   out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Might as well change `keys = config.options(ch)` to `keys = set(config.options(ch))` (could also demonstrate use of `with`)

Comment: @JonClements, edited, I was in the middle of writing the second part of my answer that uses with

Comment: Also, perhaps just name `ch` `person` in the `for` instead of the `person = ch` later on...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Many thanks! This helps a whole lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: @JaJones, no worries, using `_` when naming your variables makes your code more readable, it is also the recommended way to name your variables, using `with`  your files will always be closed for you.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if you really wanted - you could dedent this one level more... but not sure it's really necessary... you've already got my +1 :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ignore me... it just makes it too obscure - readability is important :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hey, so I've noticed that the code seems to  conduct the for loop statement only for the first person in config.sections(person). Not sure why, it's just the only outfile that gets created. Is there a python debugger for Linux you'd recommend? Additionally, only the first key is being scanned. My config file is simple '[person#1]apple[person#2]cat'. Thanks much

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Right now I'm just using kate

Comment: pycharm ide community edition is free, it has an inbuilt debugger and it is a brilliant ide for python, I have used pycharm since day 1 with python and I could not do without it now.  can you `print config.sections()` too so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: I made an edit, I think we should be scanning through `scan_file` and checking keys against that

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the suggestion, I'll pull that ide down now. I'm getting the same results though - only the first key is being scanned; the other persons in config.sections(person) seem to be getting ignored.